# How to hide apple watch app for specific version

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchos-2

I am developing an apple watch app.
 
I want the app to be available only to users using watch OS 2.1 and above.

Is it possible that I hide the watch app for users running Watch OS 2.0 or less. If not is there a way I can detect the paired watch's OS version and show a message on phone app?

Answer (score 2):

Select your Watch app target in Xcode and then go to **Build Settings**. In the deployment section, select 'watchOS 2.1' for the *watchOS deployment target*

[image]

This won't actually hide your app from the app list in the iOS Watch App, but if "show on Apple Watch" is selected, the installation will fail.

Comment: thank you. But does this mean the watch app will not be shown to the user in his phone if he is running watch OS 2.0 (my watch page on "apple watch" app)

Comment: Unfortunately the app still shows in the Apple Watch App, but the installation will fail if they select "show on Apple Watch"